# How to display specific data from JSON string?

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-sheets

I am retrieving JSON-formatted data from a Google Spreadsheet URL, as shown below. (Alternative [link to JSON file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P6ESB17Y-Jc053di12dzFuWE0/view?usp=sharing).) I just want to parse that and display the underlying data. How can I accomplish that, given that all the data I want is identified with the same label, `v`?

```
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({
   "version":"0.6",
   "reqId":"0",
   "status":"ok",
   "sig":"1326357147",
   "table":{
      "cols":[
         {
            "id":"A",
            "label":"Ref",
            "type":"number",
            "pattern":"General"
         },
         {
            "id":"B",
            "label":"ÃƒÂrea",
            "type":"string"
         },
         {
            "id":"C",
            "label":"Curso",
            "type":"string"
         }
      ],
      "rows":[
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":1.0,
                  "f":"1"
               },
               {
                  "v":"DiseÃƒÂ±o"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Flash CS4 bÃƒÂ¡sico"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":2.0,
                  "f":"2"
               },
               {
                  "v":"DiseÃƒÂ±o"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Freehand MX "
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":3.0,
                  "f":"3"
               },
               {
                  "v":"DiseÃƒÂ±o"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Illustrator CS5"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":4.0,
                  "f":"4"
               },
               {
                  "v":"DiseÃƒÂ±o"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Photoshop CS4 avanzado"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":5.0,
                  "f":"5"
               },
               {
                  "v":"InformÃƒÂ¡tica"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Word"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":6.0,
                  "f":"6"
               },
               {
                  "v":"InformÃƒÂ¡tica"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Excel"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":7.0,
                  "f":"7"
               },
               {
                  "v":"InformÃƒÂ¡tica"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Access"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":8.0,
                  "f":"8"
               },
               {
                  "v":"InformÃƒÂ¡tica"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Outlook "
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":9.0,
                  "f":"9"
               },
               {
                  "v":"InformÃƒÂ¡tica"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Powerpoint "
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":10.0,
                  "f":"10"
               },
               {
                  "v":"InformÃƒÂ¡tica"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Office 2007"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":11.0,
                  "f":"11"
               },
               {
                  "v":"NNTT Pymes"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Comercio ElectrÃƒÂ³nico"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":12.0,
                  "f":"12"
               },
               {
                  "v":"NNTT Pymes"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Estrategias implant. NNTT para pymes"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":13.0,
                  "f":"13"
               },
               {
                  "v":"NNTT Pymes"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Facebook"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":14.0,
                  "f":"14"
               },
               {
                  "v":"NNTT Pymes"
               },
               {
                  "v":"LinkedIn"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":15.0,
                  "f":"15"
               },
               {
                  "v":"NNTT Pymes"
               },
               {
                  "v":"NNTT para directivos de Pymes"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":16.0,
                  "f":"16"
               },
               {
                  "v":"NNTT Pymes"
               },
               {
                  "v":"NNTT para RRHH"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":17.0,
                  "f":"17"
               },
               {
                  "v":"NNTT Pymes"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Telemarketing"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":18.0,
                  "f":"18"
               },
               {
                  "v":"NNTT Pymes"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Twitter"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":19.0,
                  "f":"19"
               },
               {
                  "v":"PRL y MA"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Educ. para la igualdad de oportunid."
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":20.0,
                  "f":"20"
               },
               {
                  "v":"PRL y MA"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Fundament. adaptaciÃƒÂ³n LOPD en Pymes"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":21.0,
                  "f":"21"
               },
               {
                  "v":"PRL y MA"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Manipulador de alimentos"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "c":[
               {
                  "v":22.0,
                  "f":"22"
               },
               {
                  "v":"PRL y MA"
               },
               {
                  "v":"PrevenciÃƒÂ³n de Riesgos Laborales"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
});
```

The code below is what I use to save the JSON (previously read from a URL) in an array and go around to show me only data rows.

```
var data = httpRequest.responseText;
arrayDatos = data.split('{"c":');

for(var i = 1 ; i < arrayDatos.length; i++)
{
    document.getElementById("body").innerHTML +=  arrayDatos[i] + '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh god, string operations on JSON ? As you might not know, JSON is an acronym to JavaScript Object Notation. So basically you've got the String representation of a Javascript object, and rather than converting it back to the native object it's representing you chose to use String operations to work on it. Well it would work, but it would also be inefficient and harder to maintain.

So here is a sane alternative, using `JSON.parse(data)` to restore the object from its JSON representation :

```
var objectData = JSON.parse(data);
var rowsArray = objectData.table.rows;
for(var i = 0 ; i < rowsArray.length; i++) {
    var currentRow = rowsArray[i]
    var cellArray = currentRow.c;
    for (var j = 0; j < cellArray.length; j++) {
        var currentCell = cellArray[j];
        document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += currentCell.v + '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Also notice how each row has an array of cells. While your question is at best implicit, I suppose this might be your problem since your code currently splits around the cells array.